# What SE site should I use to ask a question about workplace network usage?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have what may be a small controversy at work regarding the network and the network administrator. I tried asking in the SE Workplace site but was told it's too technical for that forum. Essentially I need to know if there is a way that our administrator could be blocking certain (non-controversial) sites that I visit daily. The question needs the expertise of a network administrator, but it is ultimately about workplace harassment.

Which SE/SO site should I choose?

Comment: may be [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) or [this will help](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/100713/could-company-network-admin-be-blocking-certain-sites-for-me/100716#100716 - it seems to be causing quite a stir there, for having been labeled as off-topic.

Comment: "I need to know if there is a way that our administrator could be blocking certain (non-controversial) sites that I visit daily." - This is trivial to do as an network Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re asking for the technical information, I’d probably point you to [Super User](https://superuser.com). Once you’ve gotten the technical information, and want to pursue the workplace harassment angle, I’d point you back to [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

hmm. I'd actually suggest splitting this up. *That* your admin's possibly doing this could belong to workplace.

*How* he's doing this - gets complicated. You have symptoms. They're kinda scanty (is he editing your hosts file? Is this at DNS level?). That could potentially go on SU though there might be a few rounds of refinement needed at the current level of details, and it heavily depends on what you can get away with. Can we test with external DNS servers? Can we tunnel out? And so on.

What you do *once you've proven this* might belong on workplace. I'd also suggest dealing with the sysadmin before that from a different perspective

> My situation here is that the network administrator has a grudge against me, for whatever reason, other than the fact that he is extremely childish.

Making nice with him or getting that sorted might be a workplace question too! If nothing else, if your software's tripping some IDS - he's the best person to ask.

So yeah, rescope your workplace question - think about and polish up your technical side and ask it on SU and see what happens.

Comment: Workplace mod here.  Yes, the "how would someone do that?" question belongs on a technical site, while the "how do I get him to stop?" question belongs on Workplace.  "Is he allowed to do this?" doesn't belong on either, as it would be subject to company policy and perhaps local law.